# Oracle Linux virtual machine with VBox on Windows 10 connection issue

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm trying to configure an Oracle Linux VM - Virtualbox Version 5.2.8 r121009 (Qt5.6.2) - on my Windows 10 OS (Version  10.0.16299 Build 16299), but I can't navigate on Firefox Browser and my system isn't wired connected properly. I'm new to Linux, so probably I missed something.

I'm on private (corp) network with proxy. So I firstly configured Windows in Internet Options > Connections > Lan settings

[image]

[image]

Then I selected NAT connection in VBox and I configured wired connection with my Vbox Lan ip. I can ping my laptop but I can't ping www.google.com, for example.

[image]

So I tried Automatic DHCP, I can ping my laptop, corp. Lan and google, but I can't use repository

Trying other mirror.
http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed connect to yum.oracle.com:80; Connection refused"

Please help me to solve this connection issue with detailed steps, because I'm not expert in this environment.

Comment: You have confirmed that reason you cannot connect to the repository is not because of your proxy?  Can you update your question to include which build of Windows 10 you are using?  You should also indicate which version of VirtualBox you are using

Comment: Thanks for the repost Ramhund. I just edited. Now I finally can use repositories, I put auto DHCP for the second time and it worked. But I can't still no use Firefox. I set my proxy both in configuration and in Firefox settings. But it doesn't work.